# Firefox 3 adds spacing to spans with display:inline-block

Tags: css, firefox

In my test, I have 2 spans both set to display:inline-block with a border for visibility. Firefox renders space between each span. Even setting margin:0;padding:0; doesn't do anything to fix this. My expectation when setting the inline span element to display:inline-block is that the 2 spans render flush against each other, as if you floated 2 divs left or right. The only "fix" I have found is to add float:left or right to the spans, but that defeats my original purpose of trying not to use floats at all. Any ideas?

```html
<style>
span{
    border:2px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
</style>
<span>Test</span>
<span>Test2</span>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's spacing them apart because you have space between them - the newline.

Comment: @bombe yeah so I guess asking a question on a help site is just really stupid of me. Yeah, shoulda known that. So, do you use SO to buy airline tickets or mail order ketchup then?

Comment: you can order ketchup on here?

Comment: I had the exact same issue with the first inline item having extra padding. Thanks, this solution is indeed brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use comments to remove the empty space between the lines.

```
   <span>hou</span><!--
--><span>se#</span><!--
--><span>316</span><!-- outputs house#316 without spaces -->
```

No comments  on the ugliness (pun intended), but sometimes this is an acceptable way to keep the markup lined up correctly while still displaying correctly.

Off topic but IMPORTANT:  when using inline-block on spans, it is often very useful to turn on box-sizing (-moz-box-sizing: border-box; etc) which makes the borders & padding be measured from inside the elements.  This is the only practical way to use percentages with inline-block spans, and can save many related headaches.

Comment: Comments are a neat trick - works for me. Helpful when working with template logic like loops... and the tempting system leaves in pesky whitespace (I'm using Liquid).

Answer (score 3):

> I don't suppose there's a way to allow spans on multiple lines in the markup while not having them render the space?

Not exactly, but:

```
<span>...</span
><span>...</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ryan Mitchell's solution worked well for me. I ended up with something like this:

```
.container { word-spacing: -1em; }
.container * { word-spacing: normal; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not loving this bug. Something you might want to consider though is setting the word-spacing on the container element to -1em. I've just ran into this bug myself so I'm not sure if it's practical but it will hide that space.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. Inline-block behaves as an "inline" element on the outside. If the spaces were removed, then when you put an `<a href="...">` inside a paragraph, it would "suck" the spaces to the left and to the right.

Comment: Yeah that's fair, it's not a bug. It felt like it at the time. The big problem now is the inconsistency between browsers when trying to close up that space. Safest bet is to close up the white space manually, a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing FF2.0
FireFox 2.0 is a little trickier to find a fix for, you cannot apply a standard browser hack to target FireFox 2 without affecting new versions of the browser. You could go down the JS route but these types of browser targeting seem to be long winded and a little flakey. The best fix for this issue is to use the “-moz-inline-stack” value for the “display” attribute.

As FireFox 2 doesn’t support inline-block, but it does support a Mozilla specific display property ‘-moz-inline-stack’, which displays just like inline-block. When we add it before “display:inline-block”, FF2 ignores the “inline-block” declaration and keeps -moz-inline-stack. Browsers that support inline-block will use it and ignore previous display property.

Here’s an example:

.itemname
{
display: -moz-inline-stack;
display: inline-block;
}

---

This answer taken directly from http://www.soak.co.uk/blog/firefox-2-ie6-and-inline-block/

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Now, please don't take other people's work and use it as your own.  Attribution is always required.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rendering pure XHTML (and its highly likely you're not, even setting the doctype won't unless you serve the page to the user as XML, not HTML) then it would display as you are expecting.

However because of the above mentioned HTML / XHTML variances, it will be rendered as a single space.