# Floated list items with unwanted vertical gap

Tags: jquery, css, list, css-float

## Context:

I have a six left floating list items (2 rows x 3 columns).

Each list item contains a few divs.

## Problem:

The vertical height of the list items vary. When the vertical height of list items of the same row are not equal, it distorts the floating of the list items in the following row.

[image]

## Live example:

Link: http://alethemes.com/orquidea/our-team/

To reproduce the problem, add an extra line to the text (.workerdescr) in the first list item.

This can be done swiftly using Firebug (or any other browser's code inspector).

## What I've tried:

Firstly, I've tried wrapping a div around each row of list items but it distorts the floats of the list items in the next row.

Secondly, I've tried using jQuery to equalise the heights. It works up until I manually resize the browser width. The problem reappears at specific browser widths (if only for a mere few pixels but occurs nonetheless).

```
//Applied for when document ready and when browser resizes:
var contentHeight = $('.heightfix_listitem1').height();
$('.heightfix_listitem2, .heightfix_listitem3').css('height', contentHeight + "px");
```

## Question:

Does anyone have a neat HTML/CSS/jQuery fix that will prevent the floated list items distorting in the second row?  The fix doesn't have to be pretty or brilliant once so long as it works.

Comment: Clear the fourth item.

Comment: @j08691 : Nice solution and it works responsively. Why not add your solution as an answer? Also, thank for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, and one that takes little code, would be to clear the fourth item (`clear:both` or `clear:left`).

Comment: Please see my response to thirtydot.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to fix this.

You can switch to using `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`:

```css
.teamlist li {
    width: 32%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The tops of items in every row will always line up, and this technique will continue to work if you have a different number of elements per row (for instance through a media query).

Comment: Thank you. Using display instead of float works (in conjunction with the reduction of margin-right as your code implies).

Comment: I've chosen j08691's answer because it requires one edit less (trivial, I know) and it doesn't require the margins to be resized. On the other hand, if I were to requrie additional rows of list items, your solution is superior in that it only needs to be applied once whereas j08691's solution would need to be applied to the fourth, eighth, twelfth etc. list item. Considering I didn't stipulate this as a requirement in my question (which it is) I've opted for j08691's answer.

Comment: No problem, both solutions will work for you. If you had more elements, you could use `li:nth-child(3n+4)` to apply `clear: both` to the required items.

Comment: Tested and confirmed. Very slick. Thank you.

Comment: I've been advised that inline-block in conjunction with margin-right may present a bug in certain browsers and to instead wrap every three list items in a div (e.g.`div.list-float-fix`) with the following CSS: `.list-float-fix:before, .list-float-fix:after {content: ""; display: table;} .list-float-fix:after {clear: both;}`.

Comment: There are no particular problems with `inline-block` and `margin-right`, which browsers are you talking about?

Comment: I may have incorrectly defined margin-right as the culprit. From what I've been advised, Firefox adds an undesirable space to the right of inline-block elements in certain cases. From what I've read though, this can be circumvented by removing the new line or spaces from the mark-up (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441279/firefox-3-adds-spacing-to-spans-with-displayinline-block or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin). Furthermore, the problem doesn't seem unique to Firefox (http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: Apologies for relaying on partial advise without the necessary full context.